# Is there a way to auto create the folder in bin directory along with configuration and platform in vs2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Hi i have a solution in vs2010.I need to build it with both the platforms seperately (ie) i need both 32 and 64 bit dlls.So for each time when i build the project i need to change the Output path too.
If **building with x86 platform** then my output path should be

> bin\x86\Release\

or **if it's x64 platform** then i need to change the output path manually to

> bin\x64\Release\

Is this the only way to change the output paths..??
Because when building wix projects in vs2010 i can define a variable in project properties and i can assign the value to the output path.
(eg)for defining variable  `AddinFiles=..\WordAddin\bin\$(Configuration)\;` and for assigning it in output path like this 
`bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\`

Is there anyway like this in vs2010 for other projects.?

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<Optimize>false</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
<RegisterForComInterop>true</RegisterForComInterop>
```

even in my code i don't have any **OutDir** condition .

Comment: Right click the project > properties > build > output path

Comment: @CarlSixsmith  Thanks and i know this.This wont make sense in the folder which was created in bin directory according to platform and configuration change.

Comment: do you know it is stored per configuration? So if you switch to release for instance it's a different value from debug?